# SVN revert changes more files than svn status shows?

Tags: svn

I often use `svn revert -R some_path/` to revert local changes. However, often the command logs each file from the repository as reverted. This is strange because it happens just after a `svn status some_path/` shows only 2-3 changed files. I have also made sure that `svn update some_path` has been called before, so the local repo really only has the 2-3 changes that svn status shows...

Is this behaviour explainable? SVN client has Version 1.9.5...